# Passing data from office JS storage to Queries and Connections

Tags: excel, office-js

I have an Auth flow in my add-in that returns API token which I want later to use in my Queries and Connections (Power BI/Power Query). How can I safely transfer/read the token from Office JS storage to be usable on Power Query Editor?

Right now I created a custom excel function (formula) that returns this token, but those functions can be used only in Cells. There are two problems with that:

1. The API token will be stored in a cell and thus preserved together with the spreadsheet which is not OK
2. The power query might not expect the cell to be updated asynchronously as the JS functions are

Comment: Did you ever find a usable solution to that?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't